# Angular 2 unit test compilation failed jasmine/karma

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine, karma-runner

could somebody provide their thoughts about the error on compilation unit test for angular2 project?

```
14 04 2017 22:32:56.591:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
14 04 2017 22:32:56.627:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.6.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
14 04 2017 22:32:56.628:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
14 04 2017 22:32:56.678:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
14 04 2017 22:33:00.850:INFO [Chrome 57.0.2987 (Windows 10 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket g9NBqcx7uGTZdJXBAAAA with id 58214193
14 04 2017 22:33:01.748:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/systemjs.config.extras.js
14 04 2017 22:33:03.178:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/node_modules/rxjs/RX.js
Chrome 57.0.2987 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "originalErr": {}
  }
```

My configuration are:

karma-test-shim.js

```
// #docregion
// /*global jasmine, __karma__, window*/
Error.stackTraceLimit = 0; // "No stacktrace"" is usually best for app testing.

// Uncomment to get full stacktrace output. Sometimes helpful, usually not.
//Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity; 

jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

var builtPath = '/base/';

__karma__.loaded = function () { };

function isJsFile(path) {
  return path.slice(-3) == '.js';
}

function isSpecFile(path) {
  return /\.spec\.(.*\.)?js$/.test(path);
}

function isBuiltFile(path) {
  return isJsFile(path) && (path.substr(0, builtPath.length) == builtPath);
}

var allSpecFiles = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files)
  .filter(isSpecFile)
  .filter(isBuiltFile);

System.config({
  baseURL: 'base',
  // Extend usual application package list with test folder
  packages: { 'testing': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' } },

  // Assume npm: is set in `paths` in systemjs.config
  // Map the angular testing umd bundles
  map: {
    '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms/testing': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms-testing.umd.js',
  },
});

System.import('systemjs.config.js')
  .then(importSystemJsExtras)
  .then(initTestBed)
  .then(initTesting);

/** Optional SystemJS configuration extras. Keep going w/o it */
function importSystemJsExtras(){
  return System.import('systemjs.config.extras.js')
  .catch(function(reason) {
    console.log(
      'Warning: System.import could not load the optional "systemjs.config.extras.js". Did you omit it by accident? Continuing without it.'
    );
    console.log(reason);
  });
}

function initTestBed(){
  return Promise.all([
    System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
    System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
  ])

  .then(function (providers) {
    var coreTesting    = providers[0];
    var browserTesting = providers[1];

    coreTesting.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
      browserTesting.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      browserTesting.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
  })
}

// Import all spec files and start karma
function initTesting () {
  return Promise.all(
    allSpecFiles.map(function (moduleName) {
      return System.import(moduleName);
    })
  )
  .then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);
}
```

karma.conf.js

```
// Karma configuration

module.exports = function(config) {
    var appBase    = 'app/';       // transpiled app JS and map files
    var appSrcBase = 'app/';       // app source TS files
    var appAssets  = '/base/app/'; // component assets fetched by Angular's compiler. all assets served up at http://localhost/base/


  config.set({
    basePath: '',

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
    ],

    files: [
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

      // Polyfills
      'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',
      'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',

      // zone.js
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

      // RxJs
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      // Paths loaded via module imports:
      // Angular itself
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      { pattern: 'systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false },
      'karma-test-shim.js',

      // transpiled application & spec code paths loaded via module imports
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },

      // Asset (HTML & CSS) paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
      // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.html', included: false, watched: true },
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.css', included: false, watched: true },

      // Paths for debugging with source maps in dev tools
      { pattern: appSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },
    ],

    proxies: {
      // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
      "/app/": appAssets
    },

    exclude: [
    ],

    preprocessors: {
    },

    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

If I tried to write a test for the component, I gather error above. Thank you.

Comment: To start, there are a couple 404s: Rx.js and systemjs.config.extras.js. Is Karma configured to include them?

Comment: Yes, and It's working, but failed when I add test for component.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the below property in the proxies Object so that you can alias the nodeModules folder with base added before it.

```
proxies: {
      // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
      "/app/": appAssets,
      "/node_modules":'/base/node_modules/'
    },
```